# How is the orientation of frame /odom initialized?

Tags: navigation, robot-localization, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What determines the orientation of the tf frame /odom when it is initialized?

On the page for GPS integration, [here](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization/Tutorials/GPS%20Integration). It says:

"The odom and map frames are world-fixed frames and generally have their origins at the vehicle's start **position** *and* **orientation**."

However I have personally found that while the position of /odom and /base_link match at startup, the orientation doesn't. In the image below all I have done is move the robot directly forward, and you can see that it's orientation (/base_link) does not match that of /odom.

[image: tf /base_link]

So, if it isn't being initialized to match /base_link, how is it being initialized? Or is this a bug?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235228/how-is-the-orientation-of-frame-/odom-initialized?/) by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2327 on 2016-05-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're using a simulated Jackal. Looking at the `r_l` [config](https://github.com/jackal/jackal/blob/indigo-devel/jackal_control/config/robot_localization.yaml) for the Jackal, you can see that the yaw data from the IMU is being fused. Therefore, if at time `t0`, your simulated IMU reports a non-zero yaw, then the filter is going to reflect that. If you want it to start with 0 yaw even when the IMU doesn't, turn on `relative` mode for that sensor (i.e., `imu0_relative: true`).

**Edit in response to comments**

First, the template launch file is just that: a template. It's meant to show you what parameters are available to you, but isn't actually used by the nodes in `r_l`. The various parameters, where appropriate, do have default values if not specified, and you are correct that the `_relative` parameter defaults to *false*.

Second, note that moving the `odom` frame origin is equivalent to setting the robot's pose in the odom frame. You can use the `set_pose` service for that.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-05-31**:
Ah, I think I understand. But I'm actually using a real Jackal, and I see that in ekf_template.launch this variable is already set to true, whereas in robot_localization.yaml it's undefined. So am I correct in assuming it defaults to false and robot_localization.yaml overrides ekf_template.launch?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-05-31**:
Yeap, that did the trick. Adding `imu0_relative: true` to robot_localization.yaml forces the /odom frame to align with /base_link. Is there also a way to explicitly set the origin and orientation of /odom the same way you can with /utm using navsat_transform_node?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tom Moore's answer is correct, however for others like me who are relatively new to ROS I'll restate everything a bit more explicitly with instructions. In this instance I am referring to the frame `/odom` as created by an instance of `ekf_localization` from the `robot_localization` package, so my explanation relates to that package. The problem and solution may be different if you are using some other part of the navigation stack to track odometry. I'm also assuming that this is a ground based robot with IMU and odometry data.

## Problem

You want to know how the frame /odom is initialized and how you can manually re-set it or control it's initialization.

## Cause

In short: The *origin* of `/odom` initializes to the current position of the robot. The *orientation* of `/odom` initializes to whatever your IMU thinks is magnetic North (the heading at which your IMU reads 0.0).

In full: The frame `/odom` is created by an instance of `ekf_localization` when the node is launched. By default, the origin of `/odom` is set equal to the origin of `/base_link` - i.e. the current position of your robot. The `ekf_localization` node requires an IMU data stream as an input (default source is `/imu/data`). This data stream dictates the orientation of `/odom`. When `ekf_localization` is launched it will read the IMU data and set the orientation of `/odom` to whatever heading your IMU will read 0.0 at. If your IMU data is earth-referenced, it will (typically) read 0.0 when pointing to magnetic North. So, your `/odom` frame will initialize with its orientation pointing to magnetic North.

However, you may want to re-set `/odom` or otherwise control its pose...

## Solution

There are three things you can do to set the origin and orientation of `/odom`:

1. Initialize `/odom` to match the origin and orientation of `/base_link` at launch.
2. Manually re-set the origin and orientation of `/odom` by publishing a [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html) to the `/set_pose` topic.
3. Use the `SetPose` service to set the origin and orientation.

(There may be more options that I don't know about yet so feel free to correct me)

**Setting `/odom` at launch**

This is as simple as setting a single parameter in the launch file for your `robot_localization` instance that is creating `/odom`. Find your launch file and add the line:

```
<param name="imu0_relative" value="true"/>
```

To override the IMU data and match the orientations. The origin of `/odom` should already match.

**Re-setting `/odom` by publishing to `/set_pose`**

At any time you can publish a [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html) message to the `/set_pose` topic. The topic likely won't appear using `rostopic list` until you publish to it. Type this into a terminal:

```
rostopic pub /set_pose geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped '{header: {stamp: now, frame_id: "odom"}, pose: {pose: {position: {x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0}, orientation: {w: 1.0} }, covariance: [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]}}'
```

And replace the x,y,z,w values with whatever you want to want to set the origin and orientation of `/odom` to. Note that what you are technically doing is re-setting the *odometry* of your robot in the `/odom` frame, rather than the origin of the frame itself. So for example if you re-set the frame to X,Y = 2,3 the origin of `/base_link` (i.e. the body of your robot) will move to X,Y = 2,3 in the `/odom` frame. This is more intuitive to think about if your robot has already moved around in the real world, and you want to re-set to `/odom` frame to wherever your robot currently is. Setting `/odom` X,Y,Z = 0,0,0 will make the `/odom` frame move back to your robot and zero the odometry.

**Use the `SetPose` service**

Type the following into terminal:

```
rosservice call /set_pose <tab>
```

And fill out the pose and orientation information the same as you would if you were publishing to the `/set_pose` topic (as described above).

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2016-06-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) on 2016-06-21**:
Use the **SetPose service**：
`rosservice call /set_pose <tab>` . will let you modify the message manually.